# animation delay not working

Tags: css, animation

Okay, I have this text that I want to appear after 20s. I am using the animation-delay property but it is not working. Perhaps, I am doing something wrong.

Please help me out to get to right track..

Here is my code..

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Economica);
#text{
font-family:'Economica', sans-serif;
font-weight:bold;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-top:-25px;
animation:fade-in 5s;
animation-delay:15s;
-webkit-animation-delay:15s;
-webkit-animation:fade-in 5s;


}

@keyframes fade-in{
from { opacity:0;}
to {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{
from {opacity:0;}
to {opacity:1;}
}
```

Here is the link on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/robcabrera/wXdbL/)

Thank You for everything!

EDIT ONE:

After changing the order of the animation properties, and adding the opacity:0 in the text, I got the following

```
#text{
font-family:'Economica', sans-serif;
position:absolute;
left:50%;
top:50%;
opacity:0;
margin-left:-20px;
margin-top:-25px;
animation:fade-in 2s;
animation-delay:3s;
-webkit-animation:fade-in 2s;
-webkit-animation-delay:3s;
-o-animation:fade-in 2s;
-o-animation-delay:3s;

}

@keyframes fade-in{
from { opacity:0;}
to {opacity:1;}
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade-in{
from {opacity:0;}
to {opacity:1;}
}
```

But if I leave the opacity to 0 in the #text, the text will disappear once the animation is over.

How can I keep the text visible after the animation is done??

Thank you!

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You've specified the `-webkit` versions in the wrong order.  The `-webkit-animation` replaces the delay rule that you just set up.  Reverse the order so that the delay comes after.

```
-webkit-animation:fade-in 5s;
-webkit-animation-delay:15s;
```

You can avoid these issues if you always set a single attribute:

```
-webkit-animation-name: fade-in;
-webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
-webkit-animation-delay: 15s;
```

Don't forget to also set:

```
opacity: 0;
```

Otherwise the text will be visible until the animation starts, and:

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

So that the animated opacity is retained after fading in.

Comment: if I set the opacity to 0, after the animation, the text will disappear!

Comment: Okay I got it! I have to include the animation-fill-mode:fowards; so animation keeps on going.

Answer (score 10):

You need to place the `animation-delay` rule *after* the shorthand, as the shorthand is resetting your value to the default which is `0s` - or you could just place it within the shorthand:

```
#text {
    -moz-animation: fade-in 5s 15s;
    -webkit-animation: fade-in 5s 15s;
    animation: fade-in 5s 15s;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wXdbL/2/ (changed the delay to 1s so it's obvious)